# Method to selectively display IM messages in webchat with BotFramework v4?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I'm working on a voice-first bot using Microsoft botframework v4 and wanted to find a way where I can selectively display im messages in the transcript of my bot. I want to never display the user's messages and only display the bot's if there is something they need to visually confirm or a form they need to submit.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the activity middleware to return an empty component when the user messages the bot.

**Web Chat Code**

```
const activityMiddleware = () => next => card => {
  if (card.activity.from.role === 'user') {
    return () => {}
  }
  return next(card)
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    activityMiddleware,
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```